# Calculate UTC time difference in Excel

Tags: excel, time

Can any one provide an Excel equation that will compute the difference between two UTC timestamps.

The UTC time stamps have the format yyyymmddhhmmssZ (e.g 20160127175049Z). The difference between time stamps is at most few hours so, I will like the answer to be in minutes or hours.

Appreciate any guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the time stamps into a date/time that excel can use, use this formula:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2)) + TIME(MID(A1,9,2),MID(A1,11,2),MID(A1,13,2))
```

Then format it with a custom format of your desire.

[image]

Then it is just a matter of subtracting one from the other.

Then formatting it like `[hh]:mm:ss`